# Custom SMS message using Twitter's Digits

Tags: sms-gateway, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

I'm using Digits by Twitter and would like to use a custom SMS message.

This is apparently possible, as per this thread:  [TwitterCommunity](https://twittercommunity.com/t/digits-custom-text-message/31246)

But I coludn't find any additional info or documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update portions of the SMS by adding your app's name to the Digits dashboard within Fabric.

[image: Fabric Digits' dashboard]

Just select edit from your Digits dashboard and change your application's name to have that appear in the SMS.

Comment: how do i look for edit button? i don't see it anywhere on the fabric app

Comment: @rrrbabu Try by extending the DigitsButton and or hardcoding the R.string.dgts__login_digits_text in your String.xml

Comment: If the app was already live on the App Store, would changing these details change any of the keys?

Comment: You can edit the Application details safely without affecting the keys.